# script file for upgrade component in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla

on installing upgrade component

The error was:
JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist D:\xampp\htdocs\jeema6\tmp\install_4f9e645ee90d9\install.php
Component Update: Could not copy PHP install file.

install.php file used to copy the few files in root folder

if any way to call install.php in scriptt file

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an upgrade component that updates Joomla 2.5 whejn new updates come out then there is no need. Joomla 2.5 already has this feature built into it.